# Dynamic JsonIgnore Attribute / C# Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have 2 classes, something like this:

```html
public class Employee{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int Name {get;set;}
  public int DepartmentId {get;set;}
  public Department Department{get;set;}
}

public class Department{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string DepartmentName{get;set;}
  public List<Employee> Employees{get;set;}
}
```

Now, if I try to serialize this, I will get an error as it will try go into an eternal loop, so I know we can decorate this with [JsonIgnore].

Now, I would like to get the employees and include the department info EXCEPT the property called Employees, which could create a loop.

On the other hand, I would like to get the list of Departments with the list of employees, but avoiding include the Department property of employees which can also create a loop...

In other words, Employees have 1 department... and departments have múltiple employees... how can we get both without creating an infinite loop and an exception at the end?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is below:

First way:

1.Install the following Nuget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

2.In (my demo)controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var comments = await _context.Employee.Include(x => x.Department)
                      .ToListAsync();
            return Ok(comments);
         }
```

3.Then you need to add a specific call to your IMVCBuilder. This will differ depending on how you have set up your project.

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
```

Result:

[image]

Or:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson((x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore));
```

Result:

[image]

Second way: Use Newtonsoft instead and use ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore

1.Add the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package.

```
 Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

2.In (my demo)controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()

        {
            var comments = await _context.Employee.Include(x => x.Department)
                      .ToListAsync();
            var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(comments, new JsonSerializerOptions()

            {
                WriteIndented = true,
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
            });
            return Ok(json);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Third way:  Use option ReferenceHandler.Preserve(in .NET 5)

Starting in .NET 5,  add the ReferenceHandler property to JsonSerializerOption.You can use it like this:

In (my demo)controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()

        {
            var comments = await _context.Employee.Include(x => x.Department)
                      .ToListAsync();
             var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comments, Formatting.Indented,

                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });
            return Ok(json);
        }
```

Result:

[image]